# Create a node project with a automated script

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation

Can we create a node project through a automated script. The idea is to click a button from a webapp and internally it should create the basic nodejs project in a specific path with bare minimum package.json

For example,

(i) `npm init -y`
(ii) `npm install express`

Any suggestion will be a great help